multiple Mediated moderation
I am trying to determine if this model represents mediated moderation or moderated mediation and why. I have attached a visual representation of the path diagram for $Y_1=\beta_0 +\beta_{X1}X_1+\beta_{M1}M_1+\beta_{M2}M_2+\beta_{M3}M_3+\beta_{M1M2}M_1M_2+\epsilon_0 $
If it matters, $Y_1 = infant\;mortality \;rate,\, X_1 = state \; political \; leaning,\;M_1 = maternal \;education\; level, \;M_2 = state \;poverty \;level, \;M_3 = level \; of\; \;maternity \;  leave \; available (0 = fed \;only, 1= extra \;unpaid, \; 2=mandatory \;paid \; leave), \;and \;M_1M_2= interaction \;effect \;for \; maternal \;education \; levels \;and \;poverty \;rate.$
I have already reviewed moderated mediation vs mediated moderation and the article linked in that post ( https://doi.org/10.1080/00273170701341316).
Also, I am not 100% sure if the first graph or second would be correct. For what it matters,I expect that state politics would influence maternal education, poverty rate, and maternity leave directly while the interaction between maternal education and poverty rate is influenced by those variables but not by maternity leave and then with all variables. Wikipedia kind of clarifies a bit by stating that moderated mediation occurs when X1 has a direct effect on Y1 that isn't affected by the moderator but the moderating variable affects either path A (red in pictures) or path B (blue in pictures). My confusion comes from having multiple mediators and the moderator/interaction effects.  Also, interaction plots show interaction effects for maternal ed lvl and poverty rates.
If possible, I would appreciate it if someone could explain which graph is correct or, if neither are correct, explain how I would properly organize the graph to accurately represent my model. If any of this is not clear, please lmk so I can clarify. Thank you.


